# Replace underscores in string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string `var string = "my__st_ri_ng"`. I want to replace all underscores with single space and I want to store it it another variable. Each underscore should have a space replacement, which means multiple consecutive underscores should have respective number of empty spaces. I want to get my mentioned variable as `my<sp><sp>st<sp>ri<sp>ng`. How can I do this using jquery??

Thanks in advance...`:)`

blasteralfred

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What you need is Javascript's `replace` function.

```
var str1 = "my__st_ri_ng";
var str2 = str1.replace(/_/g, ' ');
```

You do not need jQuery at all for this task...

Comment: replaces only first underscore

Comment: Yeah, was already on it :). Should not be so drunk in the morning.

Comment: Also.. you not necessarily need RegEx :)

Comment: Please also note that you don't include quotes around the regex. I made that mistake:  `str1.replace(/_/g, ' ')` is correct but `str1.replace("/_/g", ' ')` isn't...

Comment: @Tom Well, it is correct, but does something absolutely different indeed :)

Answer (score 8):

To replace all occurrences of `_`, use a regular expression with the `g` (global) flag.

```
"my__st_ri_ng".replace(/_/g, " "); // "my  st ri ng"
```

Comment: But he wants to do it in jQuery! :) +1 for having the correct answer of these 3

Comment: you know I'll never hesitate to write a jQuery plugin for this with full-on documentation.

Comment: @Anurag: Looking forward to the plugin. Vanilla javascript is so boring! `$(this).stringReplace({search:'my_string', replace: ' ', replaceAll : true})` is much more exciting!

Comment: @bazmegakapa - thanks :) .. @Madmartigan - haha, very nice draft.. Now all I need are the use cases, a requirements doc, a design doc, functional specs. Oh, and test cases too :)

Comment: @Anurag: I would be happy to participate as a beta tester :)

Comment: @bazmegakapa - I can smell a new startup out of this plugin :P

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
var oldStr = 'I_told_you';

var newStr = oldStr.split('_').join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery or even RegEx, just simple JavaSript:

```
var newStr = oldStr.replace('_', ' ');
```

Comment: Will only replace the first one.

Comment: @bazmegakapa Hmm.. really? I'm gonna check it out.